# Show layered navigation without products

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layered-navigation

I'm trying to keep the layered navigation displayed, even if there are no products in the currently selected category.

I've removed `<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>` line from `view.phtml` 

And I removed `?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>` from `filter.phtml`

But the layered navigation is still not showing up.

I'm using Magento's RWD theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See As per Magento Standard How the Layered Navigation will be display.

1. Layered Navigation will display Based on the Product listing.
2. Layered Navigation contain the Filterable option which the generally the product Attributes. So that will be display in layered navigation.
3. General logic Layered Navigation is Depended on the Product Listing.

**`In sort you can not display only Layered Navigation with your Products.`**